# How to integrate the cxml file with magento for punchout?

Tags: php, oracle, magento, soap, cxml-commercexml

We have the **cxml file** which we have to convert into API format. So what way it will be easy to integrate in **Magento**.

```
<cXML version="1.0" payloadID="456778@ariba.cisco.com" timestamp="1999-03-12T18:39:09-08:00">
<Header>
<From>
<Credential domain="AribaNetworkUserId">
<Identity>aribadmin@cisco.com</Identity>
</Credential>
</From>
<To>
<Credential domain="AribaNetworkUserId">
<Identity>admin@ariba.com</Identity>
</Credential>
</To>
<Sender>
<Credential domain="AribaNetworkUserId">
<Identity>aribadmin@cisco.com</Identity>
<SharedSecret>foobar</SharedSecret>
</Credential>
<UserAgent>ORMS</UserAgent>
</Sender>
</Header>
<Request>
<SupplierDataRequest>
<SupplierID domain="DUNS">123456789</SupplierID>
</SupplierDataRequest>
</Request>
</cXML>
```

how we have to convert this **cxml file** into **API**?